# Nodejs MQTT: set timeout after receiving message

Tags: node.js, mqtt

After the first time receiving message by MQTT, I want to set a timeout for about 1 min. If there is no more message in 1 min, I want to notify something. Are there any way that I can do it ?

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {  
    // if in one minute timeout, there is no more message 
    // console.log("warning")
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to put a settimeout func inside callback either outside of client.on() but it did not work as I expected

Comment: Then edit the question to show what you tried and a description of what it did vs what you wanted and somebody will help you fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client.on() function will only trigger if a message is received. setInterval() function can be used outside which will continuously run after a second. Now count second and when it becomes a minute, you can notify something. Do not forget to initialize counter when a message is received or when it becomes a minute.

The following code will detect if there is no message received in a minute.

```
var i = 1
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
console.log(message.toString())
i=1
})

setInterval(function(){
i++
if(i==60)
{
console.log("No Msg");
i=1;
}
},1000)
```